# How save properties of the UIButton

Tags: uiview, uiviewcontroller, uibutton

I have two ViewControllers. I insert one UIButton with IBAction on the first ViewController. When i push on the button with set name "PLAY" after pushed i can see "STOP" - it's work great. But when after pushed button with set name "STOP" and opened second ViewController and returned to the first ViewController i can see set name "PLAY". How save properties of this button?

Also i tried any topics but it's not right for me. I used code with if/else for changed set name of Button.

Answer (score 0):

How did you do your if/else code for the button? You could try to use a flag and set the button text like this:

```
if (isPlaying == true)
{
    [button setTitle:@"STOP" forState:UIControlStateNormal]
} else {
    [button setTitle:@"PLAY" forState:UIControlStateNormal]
}
```

And then just set isPlaying to true/false once the button is pressed. Hope this helps.

Comment: Because when i returned i can see "PLAY" but i must see "STOP" because i already pushed this button.